# Storing two integer values in 32 bits while avoiding UB with negative numbers

Tags: c++

I have two `int16_t` integers that I want to store in one one 32-bit int.

I can use the lower and upper bits to do this as answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738480/pass-two-integers-as-one-integer) question.

The top answers demonstrates this

```cpp
  int int1 = 345;
  int int2 = 2342;
  take2Integers( int1 | (int2 << 16) );
```

But my value could also be negative, so will `<< 16` cause [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415895/is-left-and-right-shifting-negative-integers-defined-behavior) behavior?

If so, what is the solution to storing and retrieving those two numbers which can also be negative in a safe way?

---

**Further context**

The whole 32 bit number will be stored in an array with other numbers similar to it.

These numbers will never be utilized as a whole, I'll only want to work with one of the integers packed inside at once.

So what is required is two functions which ensure **safe** storing **and retrieval** of two `int16_t` values into one 4 byte integer

```cpp
int pack(int16_t lower, int16_t upper);

int16_t get_lower(int);
int16_t get_upper(int);
```

Comment: Convert them to unsigned integers as a first step.

Comment: @user7860670 the final unsigned-to-signed conversion will still be able to overflow.

Comment: @Quentin You could always `bit_cast`. The round-trip is safe.

Comment: What would you *want* to happen if one number was negative and the other positive?

Comment: Why not use a union?

Comment: @KonradRudolph `bit_cast` is C++20, my project uses C++17

Comment: @unddoch Because that’s not valid.

Comment: @AdrianMole I simply want to store to numbers which *can* be negative, and retrieve the exact same numbers in a completely safe manner

Comment: @Lorenzovonmatterhorn In C++17 you can use `std::memcpy` instead. But as Adrian correctly notes, once you use `std::memcpy` you can just use it directly for the entire conversion chain, no need for any bit shifting.

Comment: So, you're never going to actually *use* the 32-bit integer? You could have a two-element array of `int16_t` then `std:memcpy` that to/from an `int32_t`.

Comment: You can always `memcpy`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Using an array would require quite some refactoring of the project. I wouldn't prefer to do that

Comment: @Lorenzovonmatterhorn Creating an array from two integers is one line of code: `int foo[2] = {a, b};`. You also don’t *need* to use an array, but then you need two `memcpy` calls, and one of them needs to address into the middle of the 32 bit integer, which requires some casts. Using an array is cleaner.

Comment: Any reason you don't use a `struct packed_data{ int16_t low; int16_t high; };`?

Comment: @NathanOliver this would have to be packed to fit into 32 bit.

Comment: @SergeyA It is.  Of course the OP could use the a packed attribute, but if they plan on being in the x86-64 world there isn't a compiler that wouldn't have this fit in 32 bits.

Comment: @NathanOliver nothing in the question indicates OP is within x86-64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s the solution with a single `std::memcpy` from the comments:

```
std::int32_t pack(std::int16_t l, std::int16_t h) {
    std::int16_t arr[2] = {l, h};
    std::int32_t result;
    std::memcpy(&result, arr, sizeof result);
    return result;
}
```

Any compiler worth its salt won’t emit code for the temporary array. Case in point, the resulting assembly code on GCC with `-O2` looks like this:

```
pack(short, short):
        sal     esi, 16
        movzx   eax, di
        or      eax, esi
        ret
```

Without checking, I’m confident that clang/ICC/MSVC produce something similar.

Answer (score 1):

C++ (pre-20) makes it notoriously hard to alias values. If you want to remain within defined behavior pre-20, you'd have to use memcpy.

Like following:

```
int32_t pack(int16_t l, int16_t h) {
    int32_t r;
    memcpy(&r, &l, 2);
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&r) + 2, &h, 2);
    
    return r;
}
```

Unpack is similar, with reverse order of `memcpy` arguments.

Note, that this code is very-well optimized with both Clang and gcc in my experiments. Here is what was produced by latest version of Clang:

```
pack(short, short):                              # @pack(short, short)
        movzwl  %di, %eax
        shll    $16, %esi
        orl     %esi, %eax
        retq
```

It all ended up being the same combination of shifts and conjunctions.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution, is there any additional overhead compared to using shifts?

Comment: @Lorenzovonmatterhorn there should be none with any optimizing compiler worth it's upkeep. Will update the answer.

Comment: I'll port this into the project and run the benchmarks, if I don't see anything suspicious I will accept this answer